# How to remove AdMob ad errors

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob

I have setup an AdMob banner in my android project and I finally got it to display in my emulator correctly. So the ads now work correctly, though in the logs I get the following errors:

```
**** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
07-02 11:53:14.450      791-791/com.thibault.maaltafelsleren E/eglCodecCommon﹕         glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
07-02 11:53:14.450      791-791/com.thibault.maaltafelsleren E/eglCodecCommon﹕     glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
```

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that if the log prints error than your application have an error. That's not true. The log is not always reliable. So if your application works fine and your only consurn is the log.

### You can bravely ignore it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't know that since it seems to be something like an error log.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Emulator with kitkat (API 19) you can fix those errors by turning off the `Use host GPU` in AVD.